# How to remove blur effect when presenting an alert controller

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uiblureffect

[image]I present an alert view controller when a label is tapped . I wish to remove the blur effect when alert controller is present. Can anyone teach me how to do?

Comment: There is no blur effect - do you mean the dimmed background?

Comment: @vinciaTanqling: You need to create custom alert for that. I don't think we can control dimming the background of UIAlerController.

Comment: @bubuxu yes, the background become dimmed, is possible to make it clearcolor?

Comment: If you want to make a popup message like the Android toast, you can use many pods libraries: https://cocoapods.org/?q=toast